# EWS Notification for Calendar Delegation

Tags: exchangewebservices

Is there any API to be notified that a user has delegated their calendar to my calendar? I would prefer an event I can subscribe to that would alert me that calendar their@account.com has delegated access to my@account.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Is there any API to be notified that a user has delegated their calendar to my calendar?

No not directly in EWS you can subscribe to Folder level notifications https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/notification-subscriptions-mailbox-events-and-ews-in-exchange. However this will just tell you the folder has updated but not what on a folder has updated (eg in the case of delegation the permissions being changed etc.)

If you trying to capture Outlook Delegates (which is a different thing from somebody just going and assigning permissions to their calendar and or sharing externally) then because that also update the publicdelegate active directory property you can look at also event from Active Directory.

Also generally unless you have a real need for this to be realtime if you enable Mailbox auditing you will be able to also process this type of change by using the Audit logs. This method could also be used in conjunction with a notification to detect a certain type of change.